# XAML: How to localize a string with XML entities?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I have a localized app with all strings in Resources.resx file. This is one of the many approaches which is really designed for WinForms, but works with WPF as well.

The problem is when I want to put a non-breaking space in localized text. Entity code is converted to text. Inacceptable. So I tried to paste the Unicode character in the text, but it looks like it's converted to regular space and doesn't really work.

Of course I'm open to change localization of my app, but it's really important it should work automatically - the language should be derived from system display language. This is the main reason I use Resource Designer for it. If I could use resource dictionary and still use automatic detection feature I would switch to resource dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copied non-breaking space character from Word or any website, it didn't work, so I thought it's no way to do this.

Then I finally got the idea of inserting `&#160;` into a XAML `TextBox`, copy it from there and paste inside resource designer text.

Not a great solution, but it works. It can be sort of automated with keeping non-breaking space sample in any text file within the project. Just to copy it from there if needed. The greatest downside of this is the space totally looks like a normal space, so I won't be able to see what kind of space is in the text until I actually display it in a control.